# onPress never get fired when function is passed to it in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-props

when I pass function  to onPress it never gets fired and it only fires when the props with reference function from main component is passed from child component. AT the same time even if I enter value for usestate inside TextInput ,it returns Alert with no value. Any hep would he highly appreciated.

eg when I passed props.onPress directly to onPress, it  gets fired and calls reference function.

```
  <Button title='Add Goal' onPress={props.onPress} /> //WORKS 



function Press() {
if(enteredApiKey.length()==""){
  Alert.alert("enter a value ");
  
}
else {
   props.onPress;
}

   
   }

 <Button title='Add Goal' onPress={Press} />.  // NOT WORKING
```

but when I declare a function and pass that function to onPress , onPress never gets fired as above

Entire code is as below

```
function LoginKey(props) {
  const [enteredApiKey, setEnteredKey] = useState('');

  function keyInputHandler(enteredKey) {
    setEnteredKey(enteredApiKey);
  }

  function Press() {
if(enteredApiKey.length()==""){
  Alert.alert("enter a value ");
  
}
else {
   props.onPress;
}

  

  return (
    <Modal visible={props.visible} animationType='slide'>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={require('../assets/Image/ucp.png')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder='Enter Api key !'
          onChangeText={keyInputHandler}
        />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

        <Button title='Add Goal' onPress={Press} />       // does not works 
        <Button title='Add Goal' onPress={props.onPress} />.    //works 



        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
```

Comment: `props.onPress;` you trying to call that function?  You forgot `()`

Comment: You should probably post an answer  so that you can get the rep points

Comment: @James thanks that works. can you have a look at if statement inside inside press function. it always return alert even if I enter value for TextInput as well

Comment: You used `setEnteredKey(enteredApiKey);`, you should use `setEnteredKey(enteredKey);` You have typos.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to call function without () inside function ie props.onpress().
And secondly I have a typo error where I enter false value as argument

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).